# Constraints on a deferred update

Tags: sql-server, replication

From the online articles, I understand that SQL Server replication uses SCALL method by default, to propagate update changes to the subscriber. During the delete and insert at the subscriber, will SQL Server check the foreign key constraints at the delete process? Please let me know, if I have to provide more information...

Thank you very much...

Comment: This says that it will be fine. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366153/whats-the-best-way-to-ensure-referential-integrity-on-a-replicated-database

Comment: These Technet articles describes how to set up foreign keys and describes options for replicating them: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177288%28v=sql.105%29.aspx, https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152529%28v=sql.105%29.aspx